# Integrality gap in bilevel binary linear programming problem

Tags: integer-programming, binary-variable, duality, bilevel-optimization

I have a bilevel max-min optimization problem over binary variables, with constraints expressed using linear inequalities. The inner (minimization) problem is
$$
\begin{alignat}2
\min\limits_x&\quad c^\top x\\
\text{s.t. }&\quad Ax\geq b\\
&\quad x_i \in \{0,1\},
\end{alignat}
$$
with $c$ depending linearly on the variables over which maximization happens.

To obtain a single maximization problem, I want to consider the dual of the inner problem. I am unable to verify if the inner program is total dual integral (all I know is that the matrix $A$ **is not** totally unimodular). So I start by considering the relaxation of the inner problem:
$$
\begin{align*}
\min\limits_x&\quad c^\top x\\
\text{s.t.}&\quad Ax \geq b\\
&\quad x_i \in [0,1],
\end{align*}
$$
which can be rewritten as
$$
\begin{align*}
\min\limits_x&\quad c^\top x\\
\text{s.t.}&\quad A'x \geq b'\\
&\quad x_i \geq 0,
\end{align*}
$$
where $A'$ is obtained by appending rows of negated identity matrix to $A$,
and $b'$ by extending $b$ with a vector of $-1$'s.

Then, I take the dual of the relaxed problem, which is
$$
\begin{align*}
\max\limits_{\lambda}&\quad b'^\top \lambda\\
\text{s.t.}&\quad A'^\top\lambda \leq c\\
&\quad \lambda \geq 0.
\end{align*}
$$
Finally, I activate the maximization variables, say $\mathbf{z}$, and obtain the program
$$
\begin{align*}
\max\limits_{\mathbf{z}, \lambda}&\quad b'^\top \lambda\\
\text{s.t.}&\quad A'^\top\lambda \leq c(\mathbf{z})\\
&\quad B z \leq d\\
&\quad \lambda \geq 0, z_i \in \{0,1\}.
\end{align*}
$$

**Question:** Switching to relaxed program introduces integrality gap. How can I check the extent of/minimize its impact on the solution of the final problem?

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly and you want a primal-dual formulation of the lower-level problem you may want to consider that:
DG (duality gap)= cX-bλ (primal obj.- dual obj.). Given that, your problem can be equivalently written as:
min DG
s.t. primal constraints,
dual(of the relaxed primal) constraints,
z in {0,1}